# Magento admin menu link redirecting to 404 page

Tags: php, magento

I have created a module in magento. It will add a menu called "Clip arts" in admin, but when I click on menu, it is redirecting to `404` page.

I have added below code in `config.xml` file:

```
<menu>
    <productcustomizer module="productcustomizer">
        <title>Product Customizer</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <productcustomizercliparts module="productcustomizer">
                <title>Clip arts</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>admin_productcustomizer/adminhtml_productcustomizercliparts</action>
            </productcustomizercliparts>
        </children>
   </productcustomizer>
</menu>
```

And

```
<routers>
    <productcustomizer>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer</module>
            <frontName>admin_productcustomizer</frontName>
        </args>
    </productcustomizer>
</routers>
```

I have created `controllers/Adminhtml/ProductCustomizerClipArtsController.php` file.

I have tried same code in Local computer, It is working fine but when I use this code on server then it will redirect on 404 page.

Comment: did u try to logout and login again ? remove cache ?

Comment: Yes have do it may times

Comment: what error log says ?

Comment: I have enabled and check error log but I have not not got any error in log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming `ProductCustomizerClipArtsController.php` to `ProductcustomizerclipartsController.php` and updating the casing of the class name in the file to match the new name. Also update the casing to match in the config file. It may work locally because Windows doesn't care about casing, but if your site is hosted on a Unix server then it may be getting confused.